# Find unique column values out of two different Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to find unique values of first column out of DF1 & DF2

DF1

```
67      Hij
14      Xyz 
87      Pqr
```

DF2

```
43      Def
67      Lmn
14      Xyz
```

Output

```
87      Pqr
43      Def
```

This is how Read

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('Sample1.csv', sep='|')
df2 = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv', sep='|')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY:

```
unique_df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(subset=[0], keep=False)
```

*NOTE* : Replace `0` in `subset= [0]` with the first column name.